# 403 forbidden error in custom module in magento

Tags: magento-1.9.1

I have custom module in magento, I am getting Forbidden error like below-

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /index.php/custom/adminhtml_custom/save/id/73/key/46af940903ec3251359c2b5db00e8092/back/edit/ on this server.
```

This problem is coming after clicking on Save or save and continue edit button.

Here is the controller file which have save function--

```
<?php
class Assel_Custom_Adminhtml_CustomController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{

    protected function _initAction() {
        $this->loadLayout();
        return $this;
    }   

    public function indexAction() {
        $this->_initAction()
            ->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('custom/adminhtml_custom'))
            ->renderLayout();
    }

    public function editAction() {
        $id     = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        $model  = Mage::getModel('custom/custom')->load($id);

        if ($model->getId() || $id == 0) {
            $data = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getFormData(true);
            if (!empty($data)) {
                $model->setData($data);
            }

            Mage::register('custom_data', $model);

            $this->loadLayout();
            $this->_setActiveMenu('custom/items');

            $this->_addBreadcrumb(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Item Manager'), Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Item Manager'));
            $this->_addBreadcrumb(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Item News'), Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Item News'));

            $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setCanLoadExtJs(true);

            $this->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('custom/adminhtml_custom_edit'));

            $this->renderLayout();
        } else {
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError(Mage::helper('custom')->__('Item does not exist'));
            $this->_redirect('adminhtml/cms_page/edit/',array('page_id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('page_id')));
        }
    }

    public function newAction() {
        $this->_forward('edit');
    }

    public function saveAction() 
    {
        $filedata = array();
        $main_image = 'main_image';

        $_helper = Mage::helper('custom');
        if (!empty($_FILES[$main_image]['name'])) {
            try {
                $ext = $_helper->getFileExtension($_FILES[$main_image]['name']);
                $fname = 'File-' . time() . $ext;
                $uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader($main_image);
                #$uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array("txt", "csv", "htm", "html", "xml", "css", "doc", "docx", "xls", "xlsx", "rtf", "ppt", "pdf", "swf", "flv", "avi", "wmv", "mov", "wav", "mp3", "jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png","zip"));

                $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
                $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);

                $path = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'assel' . DS. 'custom' . DS;

                $uploader->save($path, $_FILES[$main_image]['name']);

                $filedata[$main_image] = 'assel/custom/' . $_FILES[$main_image]['name'];
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
                $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('page_id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('page_id'),'id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id')));
                return;
            }
        }
        $backgrounddata = array();
        $background_image = 'background_image';
        if (!empty($_FILES[$background_image]['name'])) {
            try {
                $ext = $_helper->getFileExtension($_FILES[$background_image]['name']);
                $fname = 'File-' . time() . $ext;
                $uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader($background_image);
                #$uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array("txt", "csv", "htm", "html", "xml", "css", "doc", "docx", "xls", "xlsx", "rtf", "ppt", "pdf", "swf", "flv", "avi", "wmv", "mov", "wav", "mp3", "jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png","zip"));

                $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
                $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);

                $path = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'assel' . DS. 'custom' . DS;

                $uploader->save($path, $_FILES[$background_image]['name']);

                $backgrounddata[$background_image] = 'assel/custom/' . $_FILES[$background_image]['name'];
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
                $this->_redirect('*/*/edit',array('page_id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('page_id'),'id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id')));
                return;
            }
        }

        $thumbdata = array();
        $thumb_image = 'thumb_image';
        if (!empty($_FILES[$thumb_image]['name'])) {
            try {
                $ext = $_helper->getFileExtension($_FILES[$thumb_image]['name']);
                $fname = 'File-' . time() . $ext;
                $uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader($thumb_image);
                #$uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array("txt", "csv", "htm", "html", "xml", "css", "doc", "docx", "xls", "xlsx", "rtf", "ppt", "pdf", "swf", "flv", "avi", "wmv", "mov", "wav", "mp3", "jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png","zip"));

                $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
                $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);

                $path = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'assel' . DS. 'custom' . DS;

                $uploader->save($path, $_FILES[$thumb_image]['name']);

                $thumbdata[$thumb_image] = 'assel/custom/' . $_FILES[$thumb_image]['name'];
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
                $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('page_id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('page_id'),'id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id')));
                return;
            }
        }


        $circleimagedata = array();
        $circle_image = 'circle_image';
        if (!empty($_FILES[$circle_image]['name'])) {
            try {
                $ext = $_helper->getFileExtension($_FILES[$circle_image]['name']);
                $fname = 'File-' . time() . $ext;
                $uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader($circle_image);
                #$uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array("txt", "csv", "htm", "html", "xml", "css", "doc", "docx", "xls", "xlsx", "rtf", "ppt", "pdf", "swf", "flv", "avi", "wmv", "mov", "wav", "mp3", "jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png","zip"));

                $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
                $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);

                $path = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'assel' . DS. 'custom' . DS;

                $uploader->save($path, $_FILES[$circle_image]['name']);

                $circleimagedata[$circle_image] = 'assel/custom/' . $_FILES[$circle_image]['name'];
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
                $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('page_id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('page_id'),'id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id')));
                return;
            }
        }

        $audiodata = array();
        $audio_file = 'audio';
        if (!empty($_FILES[$audio_file]['name'])) {
            try {
                $ext = $_helper->getFileExtension($_FILES[$audio_file]['name']);
                $fname = 'File-' . time() . $ext;
                $uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader($audio_file);
                $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array("wmv","mp3"));

                $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
                $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);

                $path = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'assel' . DS. 'custom' . DS;

                $uploader->save($path, $_FILES[$audio_file]['name']);

                $audiodata[$audio_file] = 'assel/custom/' . $_FILES[$audio_file]['name'];
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
                $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('page_id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('page_id'),'id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id')));
                return;
            }
        }

        if ($data = $this->getRequest()->getPost()) {

            if (!empty($filedata[$main_image])) {
                $data[$main_image] = $filedata[$main_image];
            } else {
                if (isset($data[$main_image]['delete']) && $data[$main_image]['delete'] == 1) {
                    if ($data[$main_image]['value'] != '')
                        $this->removeFile($data[$main_image]['value']);
                    $data[$main_image] = '';
                }else {
                    unset($data[$main_image]);
                }
            }

            if (!empty($backgrounddata[$background_image])) {
                $data[$background_image] = $backgrounddata[$background_image];
            } else {
                if (isset($data[$background_image]['delete']) && $data[$background_image]['delete'] == 1) {
                    if ($data[$background_image]['value'] != '')
                        $this->removeFile($data[$background_image]['value']);
                    $data[$background_image] = '';
                }else {
                    unset($data[$background_image]);
                }
            }

            if (!empty($thumbdata[$thumb_image])) {
                $data[$thumb_image] = $thumbdata[$thumb_image];
            } else {
                if (isset($data[$thumb_image]['delete']) && $data[$thumb_image]['delete'] == 1) {
                    if ($data[$thumb_image]['value'] != '')
                        $this->removeFile($data[$thumb_image]['value']);
                    $data[$thumb_image] = '';
                }else {
                    unset($data[$thumb_image]);
                }
            }

            if (!empty($circleimagedata[$circle_image])) {
                $data[$circle_image] = $circleimagedata[$circle_image];
            } else {
                if (isset($data[$circle_image]['delete']) && $data[$circle_image]['delete'] == 1) {
                    if ($data[$circle_image]['value'] != '')
                        $this->removeFile($data[$circle_image]['value']);
                    $data[$circle_image] = '';
                }else {
                    unset($data[$circle_image]);
                }
            }

            if (!empty($audiodata[$audio_file])) {
                $data[$audio_file] = $audiodata[$audio_file];
            } else {
                if (isset($data[$audio_file]['delete']) && $data[$audio_file]['delete'] == 1) {
                    if ($data[$audio_file]['value'] != '')
                        $this->removeFile($data[$audio_file]['value']);
                    $data[$audio_file] = '';
                }else {
                    unset($data[$audio_file]);
                }
            }

            if($data['block_type'] == 16)
            {
                $page_id=$this->getRequest()->getParam('page_id');
                $url= Mage::helper('cms/page')->getPageUrl($page_id);
                $char = Mage::getModel('character/character') -> getCollection();
                $char->addFieldToFilter('name', $data['character']);
                foreach($char as $character)
                {
                    $id= $character->getData('id');
                }
                if($id)
                {
                    $char = Mage::getModel('character/character')->load($id);
                    $char->setLink($url)->save();
                }
            }

            foreach ($data as $key => $value)             /* save configurable product id in array in database*/
            {
                if (is_array($value))
                {
                    $data[$key] = implode(',',$this->getRequest()->getParam($key)); 
                }
            }   


            $model = Mage::getModel('custom/custom');       
            $model->setData($data)
                ->setId($this->getRequest()->getParam('id'));

            try 
            {
                $read = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
                $write = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
                //$data = $this->getRequest()->getPost();   
                $blockid=$this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
                if(!isset($blockid) || $blockid=='') // check if it is a new block
                {
                    if($data['sort']=='') //check if it contains 'sort' value
                    {
                        $resultArray1 = $read->fetchAll("select * from custom where page_id ='".$data['page_id']."'");
                        $totalRow=count($resultArray1);
                        $data['sort']=$resultArray1[$totalRow-1]['sort'];
                        $data['sort']=$data['sort']+1;
                        Mage::log('ashu11'.$data['sort']);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $resultArray2 = $read->fetchAll("select * from custom where page_id ='".$data['page_id']."' and sort>='".$data['sort']."'");
                        if(count($resultArray2)>0)
                        {
                            foreach($resultArray2 as $result)
                            {
                                $write->query("update custom set sort ='".++$data['sort']."' where id='".$result['id']."'"); 
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if($data['sort']=='') //check if it contains 'sort' value
                    {
                        $resultArray3 = $read->fetchAll("select * from custom where page_id ='".$data['page_id']."' AND id='".$blockid."'");
                        $totalRow=count($resultArray3);
                        $data['sort']=$resultArray3[0]['sort'];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $resultArray4 = $read->fetchAll("select * from custom where page_id ='".$data['page_id']."' AND id='".$blockid."'");
                        $sort1=$resultArray4[0]['sort'];
                        $sort2=$data['sort'];
                        if($sort2>$sort1)//downwoards
                        {
                            $resultArray5 = $read->fetchAll("select * from custom where page_id ='".$data['page_id']."' AND sort >'".$sort1."' AND sort<='".$sort2."'");
                            foreach($resultArray5 as $result)
                            {
                                $write->query("update custom set sort ='".--$result['sort']."' where id='".$result['id']."'"); 
                            }
                            $write->query("update custom set sort ='".$sort2."' where id='".$blockid."'"); 
                        }
                        else
                        {

                            $resultArray7 = $read->fetchAll("select * from custom where page_id ='".$data['page_id']."' AND sort<'".$sort1."' AND sort>='".$sort2."'");
                            foreach($resultArray7 as $result)
                            {
                                Mage::log($result['id']);
                                $write->query("update custom set sort ='".++$result['sort']."' where id='".$result['id']."'"); 
                            }
                            $resultArray6 = $read->fetchAll("select * from custom where page_id ='".$data['page_id']."' AND sort='".$sort2."'");
                            $write->query("update custom set sort ='".$sort1."' where id='".$blockid."'"); 
                        }
                    }

                }

                $model->setData($data)
                ->setId($this->getRequest()->getParam('id'));
                $model->save();

                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('custom')->__('Block was successfully saved'));
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setFormData(false);

                if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('back')) {
                    $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('page_id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('page_id'),'id' => $model->getId()));
                    return;
                }
                $this->_redirect('adminhtml/cms_page/index/');
                return;
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setFormData($data);
                $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('page_id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('page_id'),'id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id')));
                return;
            }
        }
        Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError(Mage::helper('custom')->__('Unable to find block to save'));
        $this->_redirect('adminhtml/cms_page/index/');
    }

    public function deleteAction()
    {
        if( $this->getRequest()->getParam('id') > 0 && $this->getRequest()->getParam('page_id')) {
            try {


                $read = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
                $write = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
                $sortTobeDelete=$read->fetchOne("select sort from custom where id='".$this->getRequest()->getParam('id')."'");
                Mage::log($sortTobeDelete);

                $resultArray = $read->fetchAll("select * from custom where page_id ='".$this->getRequest()->getParam('page_id')."' and sort >'".$sortTobeDelete."'");
                Mage::log($resultArray);
                if(count($resultArray)>0)
                {
                    foreach($resultArray as $result)
                    {
                        $write->query("update custom set sort ='".--$result['sort']."' where id='".$result['id']."'"); 
                    }
                }


                $model = Mage::getModel('custom/custom');

                $model->setId($this->getRequest()->getParam('id'))
                    ->delete();

                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Item was successfully deleted'));
                $this->_redirect('adminhtml/cms_page/index/');
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
                $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('page_id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('page_id'),'id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id')));
            }
        }
        $this->_redirect('adminhtml/cms_page/index/');
    }

    public function sortRowAction() {
        $currentIndex=$this->getRequest()->getPost('curId');
        $changedIndex=$this->getRequest()->getPost('chaId');
        $rowId=$this->getRequest()->getPost('rId');
        $pageId=$this->getRequest()->getPost('pageId');


        $output['currentIndex'] = $currentIndex;
        $output['changedIndex'] = $changedIndex;
        $output['rowId'] = $rowId;
        $output['pageId'] = $pageId;
        $output['ashu'] = "sdfds";

        $read = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
        $write = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');

        $sort1=$currentIndex;
        $sort2=$changedIndex;

        try
        {   
            if($sort2>$sort1)//downwoards
            {
                $resultArray5 = $read->fetchAll("select * from custom where page_id ='".$pageId."' AND sort >'".$sort1."' AND sort<='".$sort2."'");
                foreach($resultArray5 as $result)
                {
                    $write->query("update custom set sort ='".--$result['sort']."' where id='".$result['id']."'"); 
                }
                $write->query("update custom set sort ='".$sort2."' where id='".$rowId."'"); 
            }
            else
            {

                $resultArray7 = $read->fetchAll("select * from custom where page_id ='".$pageId."' AND sort<'".$sort1."' AND sort>='".$sort2."'");
                foreach($resultArray7 as $result)
                {
                    $write->query("update custom set sort ='".++$result['sort']."' where id='".$result['id']."'"); 
                }
                $write->query("update custom set sort ='".$sort2."' where id='".$rowId."'"); 
            }

        }catch (Exception $e) {
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setFormData($data);
                return;
          }

        $json = json_encode($output);
        $this->getResponse()
                             ->clearHeaders()
                             ->setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')
                             ->setBody($json);
    }

    public function removeFile($file) {
        $_helper = Mage::helper('custom');
        $file = $_helper->updateDirSepereator($file);
        $directory = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . $file;
        $io = new Varien_Io_File();
        $result = $io->rmdir($directory, true);
    }

}
```

This code is running well on my localhost even on another server. but can't find out why it is nor working on its actual server.

**.htacess**--

```
############################################
## uncomment these lines for CGI mode
## make sure to specify the correct cgi php binary file name
## it might be /cgi-bin/php-cgi

#    Action php5-cgi /cgi-bin/php5-cgi
#    AddHandler php5-cgi .php

############################################
## GoDaddy specific options

#   Options -MultiViews

## you might also need to add this line to php.ini
##     cgi.fix_pathinfo = 1
## if it still doesn't work, rename php.ini to php5.ini

############################################
## this line is specific for 1and1 hosting

    #AddType x-mapp-php5 .php
    #AddHandler x-mapp-php5 .php

############################################
## default index file

    DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_php5.c>

############################################
## adjust memory limit

#    php_value memory_limit 64M
    php_value memory_limit 256M
    php_value max_execution_time 18000

############################################
## disable magic quotes for php request vars

    php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off

############################################
## disable automatic session start
## before autoload was initialized

    php_flag session.auto_start off

############################################
## enable resulting html compression

    #php_flag zlib.output_compression on

###########################################
# disable user agent verification to not break multiple image upload

    php_flag suhosin.session.cryptua off

###########################################
# turn off compatibility with PHP4 when dealing with objects

    php_flag zend.ze1_compatibility_mode Off

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_security.c>
###########################################
# disable POST processing to not break multiple image upload

    SecFilterEngine Off
    SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>

############################################
## enable apache served files compression
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#gzip

    # Insert filter on all content
    ###SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    # Insert filter on selected content types only
    #AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript

    # Netscape 4.x has some problems...
    #BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html

    # Netscape 4.06-4.08 have some more problems
    #BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip

    # MSIE masquerades as Netscape, but it is fine
    #BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

    # Don't compress images
    #SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary

    # Make sure proxies don't deliver the wrong content
    #Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>

############################################
## make HTTPS env vars available for CGI mode

    SSLOptions StdEnvVars

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

############################################
## enable rewrites

    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on

############################################
## you can put here your magento root folder
## path relative to web root

    #RewriteBase /magento/

############################################
## uncomment next line to enable light API calls processing

#    RewriteRule ^api/([a-z][0-9a-z_]+)/?$ api.php?type=$1 [QSA,L]

############################################
## rewrite API2 calls to api.php (by now it is REST only)

    RewriteRule ^api/rest api.php?type=rest [QSA,L]

############################################
## workaround for HTTP authorization
## in CGI environment

    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

############################################
## TRACE and TRACK HTTP methods disabled to prevent XSS attacks

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRAC[EK]
    RewriteRule .* - [L,R=405]

############################################
## redirect for mobile user agents

    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mobiledirectoryhere/.*$
    #RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mobiledirectoryhere/ [L,R=302]

############################################
## always send 404 on missing files in these folders

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/

############################################
## never rewrite for existing files, directories and links

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

############################################
## rewrite everything else to index.php

    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

</IfModule>


############################################
## Prevent character encoding issues from server overrides
## If you still have problems, use the second line instead

    AddDefaultCharset Off
    #AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

<IfModule mod_expires.c>

############################################
## Add default Expires header
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#expires

    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"

</IfModule>

############################################
## By default allow all access

    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all

###########################################
## Deny access to release notes to prevent disclosure of the installed Magento version

    <Files RELEASE_NOTES.txt>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>

############################################
## If running in cluster environment, uncomment this
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#etags

    #FileETag none
```

Can anyone help me pls to find out issue.

Comment: Did you checked your file permissions on the server ? is your web server and ftp/ssh user is the same ? could you please share the related file permission there may be a redirect to another file etc. you should share correct file permission, you may check your webserver url mapping and find the correct file in that way to check permission.

Comment: I have compared file permission of actual server with another server where it is working.

Comment: see me edited question.

Comment: It is hard say with this, but could you please add `exit("Hello I'm here");` in the first line of `saveAction()` and if you see this message, just move another line step by step untill you get the 403 again. If it gives you 403 in first place then there is probably permission error in this file.

Comment: I find this article btw, https://www.valestudios.com/fix-the-403-forbidden-error-when-installing-magento-ce-1-9-1-1/  Could you please check that also ?